# Not able to understand sorted in python

Tags: python, sorting

I have came across a code snippet to find the largest number from an array of string.However i am not able to understand how the compare is working ,since only we are passing one argument ,i.e the list ,but in **lt** method it is expecting 2 arguments.

```
class Largenum(str):
    def __lt__(x,y):
        return x+y > y+x

lgs=''.join(sorted(map(str,[3, 30, 34, 5, 9]),key=Largenum))
```

Comment: It [seems](https://repl.it/@applesoup/SE48192066) this code is doing something different from what you expect. Do you mean the `cmp` argument instead of `key`?

Comment: If you press all the numbers together to make one big number, and if you want the largest number you can get while doing that, then you will want to take the biggest lexicographical number first. Sort alphabetically, so "9" > "87654321" even though it is a much smaller number. The "less than" comparison is used internally by the sorted function. (Although it could have just done reverse=True, and not bothered with a key or cmp.)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `sorted` function obviously doesn't invoke the `__lt__` method of this class directly.  It will repeatedly invoke this method on individual pairs of members of the class in order to arrange them in sorted order.  You can easily ascertain this by adding a simple `print` to the method.

```
>>> class Largenum(str):
...     def __lt__(x,y):
...         result = x+y > y+x
...         print('# __lt__({0!r}, {1!r}) => {2}'.format(x, y, result))
...         return result
...
>>> lgs=''.join(sorted(map(str,[3, 30, 34, 5, 9]),key=Largenum))
# __lt__('30', '3') => False
# __lt__('34', '30') => True
# __lt__('34', '30') => True
# __lt__('34', '3') => True
# __lt__('5', '3') => True
# __lt__('5', '34') => True
# __lt__('9', '3') => True
# __lt__('9', '34') => True
# __lt__('9', '5') => True
>>> lgs
'9534330'
```

Comment: Thanks very  much ,and one more doubt ,why we need to inherit str class ??

Comment: I imagine it doesn't matter which class *exactly* you derive from as long as it has methods for everything (only a few of which are actually critically necessary here) but certainly you want one where addition has the concatenation semantics (or the `__lt__` method would have to be implemented differently). The `map` already converts the numbers to `str` so it is an obvious and natural choice here.

Comment: Thanks ,very much